# System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown

Tags: c#

I'm getting this error in this code

```
  public static AbilityScore GetAbilityScore(AbilitiesSort abilitySort, int score)
    {
        var abilityScores = AbilitiesScore[abilitySort];

        foreach (var abilityScore in abilityScores)
            if (abilityScore.Min <= score && abilityScore.Max >= score)
                return abilityScore;

       throw new System.Exception();   // error in this line
    }
```

i'm getting error in this line   `throw new System.Exception();`

Comment: throwing exceptions = errors. you must be new to C# and therefore don't understand the basic syntax. read up on exceptions dude. you've obviously copy-pasted this so since we cant really know what you're trying to do, we can't supply a good solution https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: By reading your code I can tell that if a valid Ability score (one between the max and min) isn't found, an exception is thrown. that exception should be there.

Comment: When i try to catch excption i getting error 'DeadPool.PerfectionManager.GetAbilityScore(DeadPool.AbilitiesSort, int)': not all code paths return a value'

Comment: Can you tell me what can i do to fix this error? @MichaelThePotato

Comment: of course you're getting that. reason being is that something must be returned from the method. your FE loop returns a value under certain conditions, and should none of these condition be met, the exception is thrown. catching it would cause the method to return no value or throw no exception as an exit. Exceptions are considered a sort of return value since they provide an exit point from the method. In short - the code you've provided seems to correct and without any visible flaws. The data your'e sending into the method isn't in the valid AbilityScore range. you need to check why.

Answer (score 1):

It just means that it could not find any abilityScore that match with score.

So, it executes

```
throw new System.Exception();
```

You need to think how to handle this case. Either throw an Exception and catch it when calling GetAbilityScore, or return null (assuming AbilityScore is a reference type).

If you stick with Exception strategy, do not throw `System.Exception`.
Derive custom exceptions from the `System.Exception`, instead.
Please read [Choosing the Right Type of Exception to Throw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229021%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: i understand what you are saying but i don't code what is code for it

Comment: @KareemNabil: _"but i don't code"_ -- then Stack Overflow is the wrong place for you. It says [right at the top](http://stackoverflow.com/tour): "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast **programmers**". You don't have to be a professional, but you _do_ have to be a programmer of _some_ sort. There is an expectation of some basic competence with programming, which by your own statement you appear not to have.

Answer (score 0):

After execution of other part of code at the end you are always throwing exception, it seems when your if condition `if (abilityScore.Min <= score && abilityScore.Max >= score)` fales in `foreach` function is not returning and executing `throw new System.Exception();` it throwing exception, so check if condition whether it is always false or not. Also in your foreach your are returning in if condition but not else so return something in else condition too

and you can wrapup your code in try catch block so when exception occure throw exception in other case not

```
try 
{
    var abilityScores = AbilitiesScore[abilitySort];

    foreach (var abilityScore in abilityScores)
    {
        if (abilityScore.Min <= score && abilityScore.Max >= score)
        {
            return abilityScore;
        }
        else
        {
           return null
        }
   }
}
catch 
{
   throw new System.Exception();
   return null;
}
```

or you can return null without throwing any exception

```
try 
{
    var abilityScores = AbilitiesScore[abilitySort];

    foreach (var abilityScore in abilityScores)
    {
        if (abilityScore.Min <= score && abilityScore.Max >= score)
        {
            return abilityScore;
        }
        else
        {
           return null
        }
   }
}
catch 
{
   return null;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean changing foreach?

Comment: @KareemNabil you are checking something inside foreach `if (abilityScore.Min <= score && abilityScore.Max >= score)
            return abilityScore;` which if its tru then function return but if not true then rest of the function code is execute so there is a line which throw exception after foreach which then execute and throw exception, this is not good practice, and seems the if condition is always false so function won't return and throw exception line executed

Comment: i replaced my code with your code but i got this error 'DeadPool.PerfectionManager.GetAbilityScore(DeadPool.Abiliti‌​esSort, int)': not all code paths return a value'

Comment: i tried your two codes and i still getting the same error

Comment: i tried your three codes and i still getting the same error

Comment: you are getting error in this line `'DeadPool.PerfectionManager.GetAbilityScore(DeadPool.Abiliti‌​‌​esSort, int)` ?

Comment: No, i'm getting error in this word 'GetAbilityScore' which in this line 'public static AbilityScore GetAbilityScore(AbilitiesSort abilitySort, int score)'

Comment: my second code which is not throwing exception must return something either null or value if `abilityScores` is not null, check carefully

Comment: Same error, i'm know this line not return value (abilityScore.Min <= score && abilityScore.Max >= score)  can you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: actually I don't know your whole solution so its difficult to find out, try debugging

Answer (score 0):

Mostafiz answer unfortunately breaks out after first failed-to-find correct abilityScore and returns null if the first item in the list is not matched. To avoid this you could try any of the follow methods depending on what suits you best.

#### 1. Using null propagation and linq

```
    // Use this if you're using C# 6.0
    public static AbilityScore GetAbilityScore(AbilitiesSort abilitySort, int score)
    {            
        return AbilitiesScore[abilitySort]?.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Min <= score && s.Max >= score);
    }
```

#### 2. Using just Linq

```
    // otherwise you can try this
    public static AbilityScore GetAbilityScore(AbilitiesSort abilitySort, int score)
    {
        var scores = AbilitiesScore[abilitySort];
        if (scores == null) throw new NullReferenceException("Target ability scores could not be found.");
        return scores.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Min <= score && s.Max >= score);
    }
```

#### 3. Non-linq

```
    // And lastly, if linq does not work for you
    public static AbilityScore GetAbilityScore(AbilitiesSort abilitySort, int score)
    {
        var scores = AbilitiesScore[abilitySort];
        if (scores == null) throw new NullReferenceException("Target ability scores could not be found.");
        foreach (var abilityScore in scores)
            if (abilityScore.Min <= score && abilityScore.Max >= score)
                return abilityScore;
        return null;
    }
```

And finally, I would still recommend you to do a null check on the AbilityScore that is returned from the use of this method

```
var myAbilityScore = className.GetAbilityScore(abilitySort, score);
if (myAbilityScore != null) {
    // code goes here...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this is what you were supposed to do. At the moment it will always throw an exception when it should only show an exception if something has gone wrong.

```
 public static AbilityScore GetAbilityScore(AbilitiesSort abilitySort, int score)
{
   try {
    var abilityScores = AbilitiesScore[abilitySort];

    foreach (var abilityScore in abilityScores)
        if (abilityScore.Min <= score && abilityScore.Max >= score)
            return abilityScore;
   }
   catch {
   throw new System.Exception();   
   }
}
```

This way the error is only thrown if it can't do the first part.

Comment: i replaced my code with your code but i got this error              'DeadPool.PerfectionManager.GetAbilityScore(DeadPool.AbilitiesSort, int)': not all code paths return a value'